# Magento Backend create order get blank white screen

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, sales-order, backend, create

I have created magento website in version Magento ver. 1.9.2.4. From manage customer=>edit customer=>create order at that time just white blank screen appear how can i solve this issues. I have attache page screenshot.[image]

Comment: Enable error reporting and do the same process once again to see the errors http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143406/how-to-turn-on-magento-error-messages

Comment: check first compilation is enable in admin or not ?

Comment: compilation is disabled.